# Random email address attached to my Apple ID

Tags: iphone, email, apple-id, contacts

I logged into the Apple ID website, and it lists my contact address as usual. But then it also has some other contact address there too. I know who it is (some random hobo who I gifted my old iPhone to). But i don't want their email address attached to my account. But for some stupid reason, there is no option to remove his address. How can I do this?

I'm talking about the "we can contact you at.... xyz" part of the Apple ID settings website.

Answer (score 1):

Under Account section click on edit and click on the ⓧ button shown besides the email address that you wish to remove.

Comment: doesn't work. Hovering over it just makes "This is an alias of your apple ID email address" pop up in a bubble, but there is no option to remove